# searching for files with stat in /bin

Tags: c, unix, stat, bin

hi im trying to write a code that will search for file in /bin directory and identify if the file actually exist, my code always turns ERROR and i don't really get why can you give me a clue?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#define MAX 4096

int main() 
{  
    while(1)
    {
       char input[MAX];
       struct stat buf;
       const char *space=" ";
       fgets(input, MAX, stdin);
       char *token;
       token = strtok(input, space);

            if (!strncmp(token,"/bin/",5))
                {    
                    if (stat(token,&buf)==-1)
                    {
                       perror(token);
                       printf( "ERROR\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {  
                 printf("FILE EXISTS\n");     
                    }  
                 }
    }
 return 0;
}
```

here's input and what it returns:

```
/bin/ls

: No such file or directory
ERROR
```

DISCLAIMER: i've just corrected question and added more so you guys can understand the problem better dont scream at me.

Comment: Please give the exact test input. Also, call `perror` to get a more detailed failure reason in the ERROR case.

Comment: @alk It's perfectly ok if there are only comments and no answers

Comment: @klutt: "*perfectly*"? Well ...

Comment: @alk Well, but at least it's considered ok :)

Comment: "*considered OK*": Not by me ....

Comment: No one screams ...

Comment: Is the code you show *now*, the code you ran *before* you posed your question?

Comment: @alk yes, its just a part of it turned into shorter code, but it works the same way

Comment: @alk Comments are meant to be temporary and they are used to make OP clarify their post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [fgets manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets):

> If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.

That is, the code currently tries to check `"/bin/ls\n"` rather than `"/bin/ls"`.

Fix by first stripping the trailing newline character. One way:

```
const char *delim = " \n";
fgets(input, MAX, stdin);
const char *token = strtok(input, delim);
```